# Embed Framworks added with Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I m developing a plugin in swift for macos

An I have added one library thanks to cocoa pods with the line
pod 'Zip', '~> 1.1'

it builds fine and the framework is added in the build directory under Zip/Zip.framwork

However I cannot have the framework on a sub directory **I need it to be embed inside the Product Bundle**

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by adding a "Copy Files" build Phases, selecting the framework and choosing Destination to "Frameworks"